Error with TinyMCE editor in Wordpress
We are currently getting the follow error when trying to edit any pages/posts etc in word press 6.61  with CiviCRM 4.74.5 and TinyMCE version 4.7.1  plug-in sion   1.5
Failed to load plugin: wordpress from url https://www.####.org.uk/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/ext/com.aghstrategies.tinymce/js/tinymce/plugins/wordpress/plugin.min.js
Any resolutions to it, It almost looks like we need to upgrade to the tiny MCE editor  to V 5
Regards

Changing the editor in Civivcrm to CK editor 5 resolved the issues!
Administer> Customise Data and screen>Display preferences >Wyswigg editor
